# replaceAll replacing the full words before and after slash as well

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a need wherein I need to replace some specific words.

For example, if my text has

```
He needs to have java skills
```

I need to replace it as

```
He/She needs to have java skills
```

I kind of achieved this with below code

```
String replacedText = originalText.replaceAll("\\bHe\\b|\\bShe\\b","He/She");
```

But the problem is when I execute the code again, the output is

```
He/She/He/She needs to have java skills
```

The problem is `'\\b'` is considering the words full even when they are before or after slash.

Update: I am getting the source from a word/excel/html file. So for the first time it works fine. My intention is if I run the code again on the modified files, it should not change anything.

How to fix this?

Comment: You could use negative look-arounds.

Comment: Your original code seems fine to me.

Comment: i can't able to reproduce your problem. Post the full code.

Comment: Simple answer.. Use `contains()` to check for (`He/She`) in the String and then use `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it with the help of negative lookahead and negative lookbehind. With this logic I can run the code any no. of times on already modified files as well.

```
private String replace(String originalText) {
    String replacedText = originalText.replaceAll(
            "\\b(he(?!/)|(?<!/)she)\\b", "he/she");
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAll("\\b(He(?!/)|(?<!/)She)\\b",
            "He/She");
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAll("\\b(his(?!/)|(?<!/)her)\\b",
            "his/her");
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAll("\\b(His(?!/)|(?<!/)Her)\\b",
            "His/Her");
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAll("\\bhim(?!/)\\b", "him/her");
    replacedText = replacedText.replaceAll("\\bHim(?!/)\\b", "Him/Her");
    return replacedText;
}
```

Thank you Biffen for the idea.

Comment: Great you found a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Few hints at start:

1. `he` `she` can re represented with `s?he` (where `s` is optional) so you don't need `he|she` (it will keep things shorter and equally simple).
2. Also you can use `(?i)` flag which will make your regex case-insensitive.

Now consider replacing either

- `he`
- `she`

but also

- `he/she`
- `she/he`

with `he/she`. Regex representing this cases can look like `s?he(/s?he)?`

So try with

```
replaceAll("(?i)\\bs?he(/s?he)?\\b","He/She");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be

```
String[] originalTexts = {"He needs to have java skills",
    "She needs to have java skills",
    "He/She needs to have java skills"
};
for (String original : originalTexts) {
    String replacedText = original.replaceAll("\\b(She/He|He/She|He|She)\\b","He/She");
    System.out.printf("original: %-32s  replacedText: %20s%n", original, replacedText);
}
```

Comment: This will fail if text contains `She/He` so you may want to add this case at start of your regex.

Comment: @Pshemo I updated the solution. Anyway it was simple enough that even people with least regexp knowledge would have been able to insert this case themself. Personally I would go for your solution. But not everyone is a regexp crack.